# Performance of Windows 2003 server vs Debian

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, hosting, vps

I'm building a Java EE web application to be deployed on a VPS.  I'm looking at [MyHosting.com](http://myhosting.com/developer-vps/) Developer VPS at the moment and have a choice between a Windows 2003 server or a Linux server.  My site will work on either, and I am happy to use either MySQL or SQL Server.

The VPS I'll start with has 1gb ram and 40gb disk space.  It also has 1280mhz guaranteed CPU.  I don't mind using Linux, but am more familiar with Windows servers and can get things done faster using Windows.

Any advice on which to choose? My site is small now but may grow decently fast.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're the one maintaining it then use what you're most comfortable with.  It will greatly benefit you during configuration and troubleshooting.  Any performance gain you might get with something you're not comfortable with will be quickly recovered when you have to put a fire out.

Comment: Good point... on a different note I'm very comfortable with SQL Server but due to later cost (if the site becomes serious), I think I'll go with MySQL.  It has some decent GUI management tools now (Workbench).